# Using Lookback API - Query Error: incomplete intersection - Release Scope Change

Tags: java, rally, lookbackapi

I am tring to use Lookback API. I want to get all features change during a release.

What I tried :

```
LookbackQuery query = lookbackApi.newSnapshotQuery();
query.addFindClause("_TypeHierarchy", "PortfolioItem");
query.addFindClause("ObjectID", "280075838440");

Map previousValue = new HashMap();
previousValue.put("$exists", "true");
query.addFindClause("_PreviousValues.Release", previousValue);
query.requireFields("_SnapshotDate", "_SnapshotNumber", "FormattedID", 
"Name", "Release","_PreviousValues.Release").hydrateFields("Release, _PreviousValues.Release");
LookbackResult resultSet = query.execute();
```

I have this exception :

> Exception in thread "main" com.rallydev.lookback.LookbackException:
>   Query Error: incomplete intersection between 'hydrate' clause of
>   [Release, _PreviousValues.Release] with 'fields' clause of
>   [_SnapshotNumber, _PreviousValues.Release, _SnapshotDate, FormattedID,
>   Release, Name]    at
>   com.rallydev.lookback.LookbackResult.validate(LookbackResult.java:101)
>     at
>   com.rallydev.lookback.LookbackApi.executeQuery(LookbackApi.java:233)
>     at
>   com.rallydev.lookback.LookbackQuery.validateAndRun(LookbackQuery.java:243)
>     at com.rallydev.lookback.LookbackQuery.execute(LookbackQuery.java:59)
>     at fr.mipih.rally.TestLoockback.main(TestLoockback.java:38)

But when I tried directly via: [https://eu1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/9396539899/artifact/snapshot/query.js?hydrate=["Release","_PreviousValues.Release"]&start=1&pagesize=2000&find={$and: [{"ObjectID": 280075838440},{"_PreviousValues.Release": {"$exists":true}}]}&fields=["_SnapshotDate","_SnapshotNumber","FormattedID","Name","Release","_PreviousValues.Release"]](https://eu1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/9396539899/artifact/snapshot/query.js?hydrate=[%22Release%22,%22_PreviousValues.Release%22]&start=1&pagesize=2000&find=%7B$and:%20[%7B%22ObjectID%22:%20280075838440%7D,%7B%22_PreviousValues.Release%22:%20%7B%22$exists%22:true%7D%7D]%7D&fields=[%22_SnapshotDate%22,%22_SnapshotNumber%22,%22FormattedID%22,%22Name%22,%22Release%22,%22_PreviousValues.Release%22])
then I get some results!

Could you help me please and show me what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in query - please wrap each field quote:

```
query.requireFields("_SnapshotDate", "_SnapshotNumber", "FormattedID", 
"Name", "Release","_PreviousValues.Release").hydrateFields("Release", "_PreviousValues.Release");
```